# How do i find a solution for a prediction error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tf.keras

I have trained a model for Rock Paper Scissor hand gesture recognizing.
When I tried to predict using model it gives a value error.
I really confused trying to find a solution and I didnt.

Hope someone will help me out

***My code :***

```
from time import sleep
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing import image
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
classifier =load_model('RockPaperScissor_model.h5')

emotion_labels = ['Paper','Rock','Scissor']

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)



while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    labels = []
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray,(48,48),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)



        if np.sum([roi_gray])!=0:
            roi = roi_gray.astype('float')/255.0
            roi = img_to_array(roi)
            roi = np.expand_dims(roi,axis=0)

            prediction = classifier.predict(roi)[0]
            label=emotion_labels[prediction.argmax()]
            label_position = (x,y)
            cv2.putText(frame,label,label_position,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
       
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

***Raise Value Error :***

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 48, 48, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your problem
Your model is supposed to predict RGB images, with 3 channel
But you input a Black & White image, with 1 channel
So, try to input an RGB image instead of a Black & White image and then your model will not raise that error

Comment: will this code make it right ? ```cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB```

Comment: I'm not sure, but try it.

Comment: i tried it and my code stucks > https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1duxfbc3hQL_wDT7CY1R-UCrd1DFIcsvk?usp=sharing